# NPM package not installed even do it is defined from the yarn.lock file

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm working on a Rails application with uses webpack (via the webpacker gem) and yarn 1.22.5, so I have the following line from my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    ...
}
```

The `yarn.lock` file is well describing it with its dependencies:

```
"@rails/webpacker@5.2.1":
  version "5.2.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@rails/webpacker/-/webpacker-5.2.1.tgz#87cdbd4af2090ae2d74bdc51f6f04717d907c5b3"
  integrity sha512-rO0kOv0o4ESB8ZnKX+b54ZKogNJGWSMULGmsJacREfm9SahKEQwXBeHNsqSGtS9NAPsU6YUFhGKRd4i/kbMNrQ==
  dependencies:
    "@babel/core" "^7.11.1"
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" "^7.10.4"
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread" "^7.10.1"
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import" "^7.8.3"
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring" "^7.10.1"
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator" "^7.10.1"
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" "^7.11.0"
    "@babel/preset-env" "^7.11.0"
    "@babel/runtime" "^7.11.2"
    babel-loader "^8.1.0"
    babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node "^2.3.3"
    babel-plugin-macros "^2.8.0"
    case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin "^2.3.0"
    compression-webpack-plugin "^4.0.0"
    core-js "^3.6.5"
    css-loader "^3.5.3"
    file-loader "^6.0.0"
    flatted "^3.0.4"
    glob "^7.1.6"
    js-yaml "^3.14.0"
    mini-css-extract-plugin "^0.9.0"
    node-sass "^4.14.1"
    optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin "^5.0.3"
    path-complete-extname "^1.0.0"
    pnp-webpack-plugin "^1.6.4"
    postcss-flexbugs-fixes "^4.2.1"
    postcss-import "^12.0.1"
    postcss-loader "^3.0.0"
    postcss-preset-env "^6.7.0"
    postcss-safe-parser "^4.0.2"
    regenerator-runtime "^0.13.7"
    sass-loader "^8.0.2"
    style-loader "^1.2.1"
    terser-webpack-plugin "^4.0.0"
    webpack "^4.44.1"
    webpack-assets-manifest "^3.1.1"
    webpack-cli "^3.3.12"
    webpack-sources "^1.4.3"
```

and each of them have an entry with all the expected details, like the `webpack-cli` package:

```
webpack-cli@^3.3.12:
  version "3.3.12"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/webpack-cli/-/webpack-cli-3.3.12.tgz#94e9ada081453cd0aa609c99e500012fd3ad2d4a"
  integrity sha512-NVWBaz9k839ZH/sinurM+HcDvJOTXwSjYp1ku+5XKeOC03z8v5QitnK/x+lAxGXFyhdayoIf/GOpv85z3/xPag==
  dependencies:
    chalk "^2.4.2"
    cross-spawn "^6.0.5"
    enhanced-resolve "^4.1.1"
    findup-sync "^3.0.0"
    global-modules "^2.0.0"
    import-local "^2.0.0"
    interpret "^1.4.0"
    loader-utils "^1.4.0"
    supports-color "^6.1.0"
    v8-compile-cache "^2.1.1"
    yargs "^13.3.2"
```

The problem is that webpack compains the `webpack-cli` package is not installed!
Looking at the `node_modules/` folder I couldn't find any folder with that name.

Running `yarn`, `yarn --force` or `yarn install --skip-integrity-check` commands does not install it.

Something else I've noticed: Some of the dependencies from the `@rails/webpacker` package are actually installed, like the `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` but not the `babel-loader` package.

I tried to install the `webpack-cli` package with `app yarn add webpack-cli@^3.3.12` which "fixed" the issue for this package, but it is very annoying.

Is there anything I'm misunderstanding? Can someone help me please?

Comment: .https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rails/webpacker sir, use npm : `npm i @rails/webpacker --save`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I'm using yarn, not NPM.